# Trouble mapping an Array of data to Images in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have a map that looks like this

[image: data]

I am using `.map()` to try to produce them as images like so:

```jsx
{theLinks.map((item, indx) => (
  <img key={indx} src={item.src} alt={item.label} />
))}
```

Nothing is getting returned, if I mess with it I can get a single img to return with no valid source and the alt is "unknown".

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show where `theLinks` is defined and assigned data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure to add your mapped array `theLinks` after or inside a `return` function, 
for example, **this will NOT work** :

```
export default function App() {
  const theLinks = [
    { lable: "Daily Mix", src: "https://flif.info/example-images/fish.png" },
    { lable: "Legit", src: "https://flif.info/example-images/fish.png" },
    { lable: "SCL", src: "https://flif.info/example-images/fish.png" }
  ];

  {theLinks.map((item, indx) => (
        <img
          style={{ width: "50%", border: "1px solid #ccc" }}
          key={indx}
          src={item.src}
          alt={item.label}
        />
  ))}
}
```

**SOLUTION 1** 
this will work (renders the mapped array and other elements too):

```
export default function App() {
  const theLinks = [
    { lable: "Daily Mix", src: "https://flif.info/example-images/fish.png" },
    { lable: "Legit", src: "https://flif.info/example-images/fish.png" },
    { lable: "SCL", src: "https://flif.info/example-images/fish.png" }
  ];

  return (
    <>
      <h1> thanks Phil for your suggestion! </h1>
      {theLinks.map((item, indx) => (
        <img
          style={{ width: "50%", border: "1px solid #ccc" }}
          key={indx}
          src={item.src}
          alt={item.label}
        />
      ))}
      ;
    </>
  );
}
```

**SOLUTION 2** 
this will work (renders only the mapped array)

```
export default function App() {
  const theLinks = [
    { lable: "Daily Mix", src: "https://flif.info/example-images/fish.png" },
    { lable: "Legit", src: "https://flif.info/example-images/fish.png" },
    { lable: "SCL", src: "https://flif.info/example-images/fish.png" }
  ];

  return theLinks.map((item, indx) => (
    <img
      style={{ width: "50%", border: "1px solid #ccc" }}
      key={indx}
      src={item.src}
      alt={item.label}
    />
  ));
}
```

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/thelinks-x6h5pk?file=/src/App.js check this out to understand what i mean it has to be inside a return function

Comment: The React fragment (`<> ... </>`) is redundant

Comment: @Phil thanks for your comment, i did some edits and explained why React fragment might be useful :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this

`{theLinks.map((item, indx) => { return ( <img key={indx} src={item.src} alt={item.label} /> ); })}`

Comment: It's an arrow function so it returns by default unless it encounters a `{`, and he used `{` to wrap so an explicit `return` is not needed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).